# Running coded web tests in VS using restsharp calls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-testing

I have a test library that handles basic response handling like sending and parsing requests using Restsharp. So for most of the tests that I write, I only have to do something like

```
ServiceClient client = ServiceProvider.GetClient();
IRestResponse r = client.createItem(item);
Item i = r.data;
```

etc and the correct APIs for create and get etc are picked up and processed

I want to create a web test to run performance tests and wanted to know if I could use the same library to handle requests for me and have visual studio know about the requests. Or would I have to use the WebTestRequest class to make calls so that VS can intercept them and return results appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

(1) The simpler of the two is to use your existing code in Visual Studio **Unit Tests**.  This would just require adding in some specific unit test code.  Unit Tests can be used in Load Tests.  To get timing for the requests, you would wrap each thing that needs to be timed as follows, and the result will show up in the load test results:

```
TestContext.BeginTimer("createItem");
IRestResponse r = client.createItem(item);
TestContext.EndTimer("createItem");
```

(2) Convert your test code into Visual Studio **Coded Web Tests**.  This would be more work, as you guessed, because instead of all the request detail being nicely hidden away and handled by Restsharp, you would have to use the WebTestRequest class.  In other words you would lose all the benefit of Restsharp.  Web Tests do have better performance because the execution engine uses asynchronous processing with a thread pool, but unless you are hardware-constrained for load generation, this isn't really a concern.